# Amazon RDS snapshot creation using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation, devops

How to create RDS snapshot from the existing RDS instance using CloudFormation?

Comment: Enabling automatic snapshots? Or are you referring to manual snapshots?

Comment: I would like to create a snapshot from my existing rds instance using cloudformation

Answer (score 3):

That is an incorrect use of Amazon CloudFormation.

CloudFormation is used to launch infrastructure in a repeatable, reliable manner. For example, launch an EC2 instance or an RDS instance.

Creating a snapshot, however, is an *action* to perform on existing infrastructure. The act of creating a snapshot is an action performed on an existing RDS database -- it does not actually create new infrastructure.

You can certainly use CloudFormation to launch a new RDS instance *from* a snapshot, but not to *create* a snapshot.

If you wish to create a snapshot, you could do it from the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or programmatically via an API call from an SDK.